# How can I use JS to smooth-scroll and highlight a parent div via search form?

Tags: javascript, html

If a user inputs a name into the search form, how do I get JavaScript to smooth-scroll to — and importantly, clearly highlight — the searched-for text's parent div (let’s say with a colored border), all within a page of many divs in a grid?

Also, if multiple results are found on the page, is it possible to get the form’s submit "Find" value to change to "Next" which — when the button is clicked/tapped, — will smooth-scroll to and highlight the next result if it exists?

Here’s my test page:

https://theswimmingpool.com.au/the-swimmers/

I’ve tried, but only been able to make the searched-for text highlighted (CSS background red), and it’s not obvious enough for users on most devices. Which is why I’d like to highlight the parent div somehow. And it’s not smooth-scrolling but jumping to the result?

The text search currently is not functioning at all on the Safari browser and I can’t see anything in the console saying why?

Thanks very much.

HTML form:

```
<div id="stickysearch">
    <div>
        <h4><strong>Search for a swimmer</strong></h4>
        <form id="f1" name="f1" action="" onsubmit="if(this.t1.value!=null &amp;&amp; this.t1.value!='')
findString(this.t1.value);return false">
<input type="text" id="t1" name="t1" value="" size="20" placeholder="Enter a name">
<input type="submit" name="b1" value="Find">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var TRange=null;

function findString (str) {
 if (parseInt(navigator.appVersion)<4) return;
 var strFound;
 if (window.find) {

  // CODE FOR BROWSERS THAT SUPPORT window.find

  strFound=self.find(str);
  if (!strFound) {
   strFound=self.find(str,0,1);
   while (self.find(str,0,1)) continue;
  }
 }
 else if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft")!=-1) {

  // EXPLORER-SPECIFIC CODE

  if (TRange!=null) {
   TRange.collapse(false);
   strFound=TRange.findText(str);
   if (strFound) TRange.select();
  }
  if (TRange==null || strFound==0) {
   TRange=self.document.body.createTextRange();
   strFound=TRange.findText(str);
   if (strFound) TRange.select();
  }
 }
 else if (navigator.appName=="Opera") {
  alert ("Opera browsers not supported, sorry...")
  return;
 }
 if (!strFound) alert ("Sorry, Swimmer '"+str+"' can’t be found.")
 return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('t1').addEventListener('input', function(e) {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('wpb_single_image');
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].classList.remove('swim-srch-actv')
    }

});

function findString(str) {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('wpb_single_image');
    var nextButton = document.getElementById('b1');
    var currentIndex = -1;
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if (elements[i].classList.contains('swim-srch-actv')) {
            currentIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].classList.remove('swim-srch-actv')
    }
    if (str.trim() !== '') {
        var found = false;
        for (var i = currentIndex + 1; i < elements.length; i++) {
            var swimmerText = elements[i].textContent || elements[i].innerText;
            if (swimmerText.toLowerCase().includes(str.toLowerCase())) {
                currentIndex = i;
                elements[i].classList.add('swim-srch-actv')
                elements[i].scrollIntoView({
                    behavior: 'smooth',
                    block: 'center'
                });
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (found) {
            if (currentIndex === elements.length - 1) {
                nextButton.value = 'Find';
            } else {
                nextButton.value = 'Next';
            }
        } else {
            alert("Sorry, no more '" + str + "'s can be found.");
            nextButton.value = 'Find';
        }
    } else {
        alert("Please enter an existing swimmer's first or last name.");
    }
}
```